# Некорректное отображение изображений в RecyclerView (Android)

Tags: android, recyclerview, imageview

Вопрос по xml-разметке. В RecyclerView идет подгрузка картинок разного размера. Кроме картинок есть другие элементы. В параметрах ImageView, отображающему изображение, ширину и высоту указываю match parent. В итоге по ширине изображение отображается на всю ширину элемента списка, а по высоте возникает проблема: появляются какие-то поля сверху и снизу изображения, причем размер этих полей разный в каждой ячейке и никак не зависит от размера изображения. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Эти поля исчезают, если зафиксировать высоту ячейки, но тогда изображение, понятное дело, не растягивается по ширине. Как сделать так, чтобы изображение заполняло элемент списка без этих полей сверху и снизу, при этом растягивалось на всю ширину элемента?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы размеры картинки и виджета соответствовали друг другу, нужно установить атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Так же, возможно понадобится изменить параметр `android:scaleType`. По умолчанию используется `"fitCenter"`, но вполне вероятно, что больше подойдет `"centerCrop"` или [другой](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php).

Comment: Помогло. Благодарю. Столько времени потерял из-за одной строчки.